# How to kendo grid id binding?

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

This my data table I want to add grid (data-uid) guid , 
or I want to change , because Kendo grid id was automatically generated

[image]

and this my grid table
[image]

How do I change the data-uid?

```
schema: {
            model: {

            fields: {
                c_Name: { type: "string" },
                c_LastName: { type: "string" },
                c_IdCity: { type: "string" },
                c_IdTown: {type:"string"},
                c_ID: {type:"string"}
            },

        }
    },
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the `data-uid` attribute is internally set and cannot be changed. It changes with each reload of the grid.